# Anyone can identify this moth?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, lepidoptera

Found on the ceiling of my flat.

Place: London, UK

Date: 9th of August

Size I would say slightly more than inch and inch and half (3-4cm) wingspan

Suspect on the photo:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks very much like a brown color morph of the [Box tree moth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cydalima_perspectalis) ([*Cydalima perspectalis*](https://inpn.mnhn.fr/espece/cd_nom/645061)), which has been seen in the UK since 2008. The size is about right (around 4.0-4.5 cm wingspan).

This species is an [invasive](https://www.cabi.org/isc/datasheet/118433) [pest](https://www.gardensillustrated.com/news/box-tree-moth-caterpillar-solution-national-trust/) outside of its native range (Asia).

[image]
By Nagy Sándor (NagySandor.EU) [CC BY 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0), [Link](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=35223756)

According to the [Royal Horticultural Society](https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?pid=760) this species has been invading the UK from the southeast with London a likely place to find them.